# Pickling array.array in 2.4 using cPickle

Tags: python, pickle, monkeypatching, python-2.4

I am working on a project built on python 2.4 (It is an embedded python project, so I don't have a choice on the version of python used).  Throughout the application, we use `array.array` to store data.

Support for pickling `array.array` objects was added to `pickle` (and `cPickle`) in 2.5.  We have a viable workaround in 2.4 when using the pure python pickle class (we subclass Pickler/Unpickler to handle arrays) but this does not work with cPickle (we need this due to performance problems).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard library module [copy_reg](http://docs.python.org/library/copy_reg.html?highlight=copyreg) to register functions to deal with pickling instances of types that don't natively support pickling; `cPickle` will use your registered functions where needed.  I'd apply exactly this "hook" approach to your requirement of pickling instances of `array.array`.

Comment: Excellent!  I've gotten it working.  Your suggestion led me to http://effbot.org/librarybook/copy-reg.htm , which provides a couple excellent examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the array type can be augmented with a `__reduce__` method (perhaps with a subclass), but you could always try converting your arrays to sequences & back again... if the built-in extension mechanism won't work for you. (hack)

I haven't tried this before, but you could try adding support via [copy_reg](http://docs.python.org/library/copy_reg.html#module-copy_reg)... essentially the same result as implementing `__reduce__` on your own class or subclass, but a tad cleaner.

Comment: For arrays I would convert them to a large string object with `.tostring()`, which is just a copy of the in-memory bytes representing the array.

Comment: With this approach you would also want to include the array's typecode.

I've tried this approach but am running into problems getting the typecode state into the unpickled object.  I've been trying to figure out `__initargs__` to little avail... I think I am going to take the `copy_req` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can pickle them, but you can't unpickle the result

```
Python 2.4.5 (#2, Jan 21 2010, 20:05:55) 
[GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> import array
>>> a=array.array('i','12345678')
>>> pickle.dumps(a,2)
'\x80\x02carray\narray\nq\x01)\x81q\x02.'
>>> b=pickle.loads(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: array() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Looks the the dumps doesn't even include information about the typecode..or even the data :(

```
>>> a=array.array('c','abcdefghijkl') 
>>> pickle.dumps(a,2)                                                                                                                                                                             
'\x80\x02carray\narray\nq\x01)\x81q\x02.'
>>>
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to confirm this bug from the python mailing list: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-January/031597.html

The "smarts" were added in 2.5

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that seems to be working (thanks for the suggestions):

```py
# Add serialization for array objects
def array_unpickler(data):
    return array.array(data[0], data[1:])
def array_pickler(arr):
    return array_unpickler, ("%s%s" % (arr.typecode, arr.tostring()),)
copy_reg.pickle(array.ArrayType, array_pickler, array_unpickler)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2338001/2) to the question [Pickling array.array in 2.4 using cPickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338001/pickling-array-array-in-2-4-using-cpickle) by the OP [Paul Osborne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7049/paul-osborne) under CC BY-SA 2.5.</sub>